# Adding new hard drive as /home after installation

Tags: arch-linux, mount, fstab

I have a desktop PC running Arch Linux that during inital installation only used a 120GB SSD for `/` and no other partitions. I have just recently added a 500GB HDD that I want to mount as `/home` to give me added storage, avoid future issues with compiling on an SSD, and help with easier upgrades in the future if I ever change anything but want to retain the same `/home`.

Prior to this my fstab read:

```
# <file system> <dir>   <type>  <options>   <dump>  <pass>
/dev/sda1               /           ext4        rw,data=ordered,noatime,nodiratime,discard,erros=remount-ro 0 1
```

When preparing for the upgrade I copied all of `/home` to the new partition then renamed `/home` to `/home_old` and created a new, empty `/home` then modified `/etc/fstab` to read:

```
# <file system> <dir>   <type>  <options>   <dump>  <pass>
/dev/sda1               /           ext4        rw,data=ordered,noatime,nodiratime,discard,erros=remount-ro 0 1
/dev/sdb1               /home           ext4        rw,nodev,nosuid,erros=remount-ro    0 2
```

... Which at the time were the correct partition names.

However, I rebooted and it mounted the SSD as `/` and `/home`. I tried it with UUIDs and received the same result.

Just for the sake of trying, I switched the two and it fell back to an emergency console at boot time. Again tried with UUIDs with the same result.

If I go back to the old version of `/etc/fstab` now, it shows the SSD as `/dev/sdb1` and the HDD as `/dev/sda1` but still mounts the SSD as `/`, which I find VERY strange.

My question, given the backstory now, is how do I fix this issue and why is it behaving this way so I can understand what's causing this?

**EDIT:**

As Timothy Martin pointed out in the comments I made a typo in fstab and it turns out that's what caused it. More proof that weird things occur when you make a mistake in your configuration files.

**sheepish grin**

Comment: Congratulations on a lucid and clearly written question. The correspondence of hard disks with device names is usually very stable. The behavior you describe does indeed seem odd. I'd start by taking a look at boot logs, specifically `dmesg`. I'd compare them for different configurations. This isn't very helpful, but nothing else comes to mind at the moment.

Comment: Can you paste the output of `lsblk -f` into the question? This is as good a way as any of displaying the partitions and filesystems.

Comment: @FaheemMitha correspondence between device names and hard disks isn't stable (especially with multiple controllers, USB disks, and Firewire disks), that's why UUIDs are used nowadays.

Comment: Apparently I'm out of date. Can you post how you wrote `/etc/fstab` using UUIDs?

Comment: Is the `erros=` intentional?  The only documentation I can find says `errors=`.

Comment: Ok, so here's the part where I feel stupid for not catching that. I corrected it to errors= and it worked. To make sure that was it, I went back and tried the exact same configuration with the typo and that was what caused it. I figure it simply didn't mount /dev/sdb1 as /home because it didn't understand the parameter and for some reason mount / again as /home...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a temporary Home folder

```
blkid
```

This will display the UID of all the partitions. Record the UUID of the dd

Open a terminal and type the following:

```
 vi /etc/fstab
```

and add the following line to the end of the file.

```
UUID=xxx-xxxxx-xxxxx   /media/home    ext4          nodev,nosuid       0       2
```

save and exit

Next, create a mount point:

```
 mkdir /media/home
```

and reload the updated fstab.

```
mount -a
```

we need to remove the existing Home folder to make way for the new Home folder in the 500 GB partition . To do that, type the following commands in the terminal:

```
cd /
sudo mv /home /home_backup
sudo mkdir /home
```

Mount the new Home folder

```
vi /etc/fstab
```

All you have to do is to change the `/media/home` to `/home` . Save and exit the file.
 reload the fstab file:

```
mount -a
```

removing the Home_backup folder

```
 rm -rf /home_backup
```

Comment: I can't figure out what you're doing here. Why edit `fstab` multiple times? Why are you temporarily mounting something on `/media/home`?

Comment: I have gone back and edited my original post to point out my mistake. For future viewers I am marking this as the correct answer as it is correct and would have worked had I not made a stupid mistake.